# Chemical used to clean washing machines

Tags: cleaning, washing-machine, limestone

I have an LG WD1457RD washer-dryer that's been working pretty well for me, except that where I live (southeast Mexico) there's a lot of limestone so the water is very hard and leaves stains on everything. Once I had the machine taken for maintenance but the guy that did it ended up charging me a ridiculous amount for some apparently broken parts... which I am pretty sure he might've broken.

Recently I had a clog issue and decided to take matters in my own hands so I removed the top cover and managed to clean up the clog and the washer actually ended up working pretty normally.

One of the issues I've been having is with the dryer where it just doesn't dry the clothes even after a couple of cycles, but that's not my main issue here.

The issue is that the holes where water comes out to dissolve the detergent get clogged with limestone and I have to periodically clean them (i basically use a small nail and break the clogged limestone). Here people use a lot of hydrochloric acid to clean limestone, but I think it's too aggressive for sensitive machinery as it can eat through other materials.

Also, my detergent bay sometimes ends up with leftover detergent which then dries up and forms like a layer of limestone detergent mix which just doesn't go with that acid, I've tried it separate from the machine of course.

My question is, is there some special chemical to clean those machines or do I have to take everything apart and submerge only the applicable parts in acid?

Comment: Citric acid and acetic acid (vinegar, at 5% concentration) are common "not so aggressive" acids used for cleaning things. Citric is commonly available as a dry powder (mix with water to suit - 5% is still reasonable) and is somewhat stronger than vinegar.

Comment: Yes, but should I remove the parts from the washing machine to clean them or can I fill the machine with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLR works great for getting rid of line deposits. It can be used as a general washing machine cleaner when added to the machine (with no clothes) and run through a cycle. 
As far as your dryer is concerned, check the vent pipe for blockage, especially where it exits your house. Many have screens that can get blocked by lint over a long period of time.

This is copied from the CLR website:

Depending on whether you have a front or top loading machine, your directions for adding CLR are different. In both cases, though, do not use detergent or have clothes in the washer when you are using CLR. With a top loading machine, run your machine up to the main wash cycle and just before the machine starts to agitate, stop the machine. Add a ½ cup of CLR into the tub of the machine and finish the cycle.

When cleaning front loading machines, though, you need to change how you add the CLR. In front loading washing machines, the door locks once you begin the cycle. As a way around this issue, add a ½ cup of CLR to the machine where you normally would add your detergent or softener and run your machine.

With both types of washers, once the cycle with the CLR has finished, run an additional full cycle with just water. If your machine is high efficiency or “water saver” only use ¼ cup of CLR.

Comment: I suppose you refer to [this](https://www.amazon.com.mx/Jelmar-CLR-Enhanced-Calcium-Remover-28OZ/dp/B00009EFEX/ref=asc_df_B00009EFEX/?tag=gledskshopmx-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=360418487671&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10367985275824134632&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1010205&hvtargid=pla-403917110787&psc=1) . So I just put my washing machine in self-clean mode wait for it to drain and start pouring this in the bay? Or how would it work?

Comment: @MihailMinkov I edited my answer to explain how it would work.

Comment: Ok, sound pretty straight forward, just one last question, as I am not 100% of the machine's process. Normally if I pour liquid in the bay it goes straight down, I am not sure if it stays there or goes directly to the main internal area. In cases like this do I have to wait for the machine's automatic drain when it starts the cycle and then pour the solution in the bay?

Comment: Also, in the specific case of the base and the water pouring, I guess the internal cleaning won't affect those I suppose I have to find a way to dismantle them and soak them in a solution of CLR?

Comment: Pour in the CLR right when the tank stops filling for the wash cycle.  It will circulate through the internal parts and then out when the drain cycle starts. The base would be a separate cleaning.

Comment: Ok, I'll order it and see what happens :)